# Web Application ASP.NET Core do not open home page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.0

I'm studying .net and created an asp.net core webapplication.
I'm using .net core 3.1.

I started my application following Microsoft tutorial to start a web application on the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows

So, for default, when an application is created and to be running, will be possible to access a default page like in the image: [image].

But in my case, I received an error on the frontend but no error in the visual studio.
See images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, after some tests, a new error has been showing on the web browser:

```
Não é possível acessar esse site
A conexão foi redefinida.
Tente:

Verificar a conexão
Verificar o proxy e o firewall
Executar o Diagnóstico de Rede do Windows
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

So, I can't continue with my study.

Someone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Run your command prompt(cmd) as administrator. It may fix your issue. Or if you are running from visual studio, run your visual studio as administrator.

Comment: Please don't paste images of errors. Particularly don't paste images of errors that aren't in English on an English language website, now we can't even copy and paste it to Google Translate.

Comment: @MehrdadBabaki running as administrations do not solve the problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @JonP Sorry. I am only want to show the pages. On the images, do not have an anyone error message. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: The tutorial you're following doesn't mention VS. Does your screenshot means you're trying in both console & VS? What's the URL being called?

Comment: "But in my case, I received an error on the frontend but no error in the visual studio. See images:" - the image is of an error, I am assuming, but I can't tell as it is not in English, and I can't copy and paste it to translate.

Comment: @Martheen Yes, so, first in one, then I close and MS DOS and open VS and try running my app. The error is the same in both cases.

Comment: @JonP, the message in the web browser says: This page is not functioning. No one data was sent for localhost. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Sorry more one time for portuguese message error!

Comment: It's probably unrelated, but my coworker suddenly has their .NET Core app broken on their Windows box, but somehow works if they run/debug from a new user.

Comment: As your error says firewall, so port 5000 and 5001 might be blocked on your firewall

Comment: @MehrdadBabaki I made a port liberation to udp and tcp but the problem happen yet.
Now, a New Error appear for me when I try to run my app. ```An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.```

Comment: Probably, the port had been blocked, that's why you can see a new error. Now I guess you may not have a proper version of .net. If your project is .net 3.1 then install Hosting Bundle from this link: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: @MehrdadBabaki this is not the problem, because it was installed. But I reinstalled it and the problem persists.

Comment: Did you debug your code at all? Does it get into the entry point of your application?

Comment: @MehrdadBabaki the code it's ok, other person had run in another machine and it's ok. No problem with my code. I think that the problem is with my laptop.

Comment: I don't mean code is wrong. I thought you may get more clue when debugging. You may also find more information inside Event Viewer. Based on the error message I still think your issue is related to .net version. By the way, It seems you stuck for a long time. If you couldn't fix the issue let me know, I may be able to help you to fix it if share your screen.

Comment: @MehrdadBabaki, thanks for all. At the moment I stopped the studies in .net platform, but I think my problem is my machine. So, more one time, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I accidentally deleted
**@page**
directive from *.cshtml* file. Without it the page is not registered and can't be accessed. It was a stupid mistake but I wasted hours to fix it.